maven project JSF 3.0 with jakarta 10 run error
I have a Maven project for a JSF 3.0 web application :
Tomcat 10.1.20
JDK 21
JSF 3.0
CDI 3.0
I use Netbeans version 21 and this is my pom.xml file :
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.afterbit.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>BoilerPlate_JSF_3_0_wit_maven</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>BoilerPlate_JSF_3_0_wit_maven</name>
    
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jakarta.faces.version>3.0.0</jakarta.faces.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    <jakartaee>10.0.0</jakartaee>
  </properties>
    
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>${jakartaee}</version>
   
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
      <version>${jakarta.faces.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
      <version>${jakarta.faces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
    <!-- other dependencies -->
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>    
      
    
  </dependencies>
  
   
    
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>21</source>
          <target>21</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

and web.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
         version="6.0">
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    <!-- Disables URL-based sessions (no more 'jsessionid' in the URL using Tomcat) -->
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  </session-config>
  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

but unfortunately when I go to run the project I get the following error:
04-May-2024 10:24:02.631 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [C:\apache-tomcat-10.1.20\conf\Catalina\localhost\BoilerPlate_JSF_3_0_wit_maven.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:635)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:484)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1703)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1477)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:971)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:334)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:41002)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:54)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BoilerPlate_JSF_3_0_wit_maven]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
jakarta.enterprise.event.ObserverException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:304)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:725)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:103)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:187)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:126)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
    at jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:142)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent._fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:41004)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:404)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:80)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize(WeldServletLifecycle.java:178)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4880)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:635)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1703)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1477)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:971)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:334)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:41002)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedType)'
    at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension.beforeBeanDiscovery(FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
    ... 65 more

        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:46)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:54)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:404)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:80)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize(WeldServletLifecycle.java:178)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4880)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        ... 44 more
        Suppressed: jakarta.enterprise.event.ObserverException
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:304)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:725)
            at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
            at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:78)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:103)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:187)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:126)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
            at jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:142)
            at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent._fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:41004)
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
            ... 51 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedType)'
            at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension.beforeBeanDiscovery(FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension.java:77)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
            ... 65 more

I tried to change different configurations in the pom.xml file for example I added:
<dependency>
         <groupId>javax</groupId>
         <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.1</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

but in the end I always get the same error.
